Google Play Pre-launch DetailsCrashes and ANRs: Generic Small Desktop (x86) (virtual) error while google play console testing
Process: com.abc.xyzz
PID: 10136
UID: 10163
Flags: 0x28e8be44
Package: com.abc.xyzv v1(1.0)your text
Foreground: No
Process-Runtime: 308400
Build: Google/Small Desktop (x86)/SmallDesktop.x86:12/SE2B.220326.027/9241628:userdebug/dev-keys
Loading-Progress: 1.0
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while disconnecting UiAutomation@9e57a7b[id=-1, flags=0]
at android.app.UiAutomation.disconnect(UiAutomation.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation.finish(Instrumentation.java:267)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.finish(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:9)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:18)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2278)
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:571)
at android.app.IUiAutomationConnection$Stub$Proxy.disconnect(IUiAutomationConnection.java:527)
at android.app.UiAutomation.disconnect(UiAutomation.java:390)"

I am trying to understand the problem so that I can solve it.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Exactly the same problem here. Did you find a solution?
Detected on:
Generic Small Desktop (x86) (virtueel)
1366x768
Android 12L (SDK 32)
x86_64
